# How to have working buttons after refreshing a section with ajax?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I would like to use JQuery to update some sections after clicking on a button. Below is the code I am developping.
If I click on the div tag with the class `previous-wrapper`, I will get the attribute `data-nb`, then pass it to ajax and get a new table content based on that attribute.
The column `action` of the table has a dropdown menu with two options: `cancel` and `edit`. Both actions are handled in another JQuery file based on click event. The first time the page is loaded, both options work fine. But after updating the body section of the table, they no longer work. I thought the way I handled it would have [Propagated the events](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/).
Is there a better way to do that ?

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12 container-content">
            <table class="table table-striped table-content">
                <thead class="table-primary text-center align-middle">
                <tr>
                    <th scope="col">#</th>
                    <th scope="col">action</th>
                </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody class="table-body">
                    <?php $fetch_data->get_data($number); ?>
                </tbody>
            </table>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="previous-wrapper">
                    <span class="previous" data-nb="100">Previous</span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
$(function(){ 
 $(document, '.container-content').on('click','.previous-wrapper',function(event){
    event.preventDefault(); 
    var get_nb = $(this).find('.previous');
    get_nb = get_nb.attr("data-nb");
    get_nb = parseInt(get_nb) - 5;

   var postContent = {'action': '1', 'offset':get_nb};
   $.ajax({
     url: ajaxURL,
     method:'POST',
     data: postContent,
     success:function(data)
     {
       // data contains a new table.
       $(".table-body").html(data);
       get_nb .attr('data-nb', get_nb );
     }
   });
    });
 });
```

Comment: `$('.container-content')` is what you need

Comment: Thank you @mplungjan. I will try that. But I don't understand what the difference will be. Can you comment on that?

Comment: If I have to be honest, I have never seen a scope as the first parameter. Normally it is the second. And document is default anyway. Other than that I do not see any improvement

Comment: Also if the code works, it is the wrong forum. Ask in codereview instead